# yarn install can't find package but npm install can

Tags: npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

I'm using yarn to manage my `npm` packages. If I do `npm install`, it all works fine. However, if I try doing `yarn install` it fails with the following error:

```
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Couldn't find package "ag-grid" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

This is pointing to an internal repository. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying various things and going through way too many Google pages, I've figured it out.

The problem was that I was setting the following in `.npmrc`:

```
registry=https://internal-repo.com/some-path
```

while it required a trailing slash:

```
registry=https://internal-repo.com/some-path/
```

Comment: It was also my problem on `yarn config list`, my repository was missing a trailing slash